# What to change in script to start on pageload instead of click?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script to work a timer so I can track time on projects.  This script currently doesn't start until I click start, which is perfect for starting to track a project but if I've started a project and either closed the browser or closed the page, when I come back to the page, I need to be able to set the starting seconds and have it running when the page loads.  I know how to set the seconds to start at but I don't know what to change in the script via PHP to have the timer running and the start/stop button set to "stop".

In short, I'd like a flag I can change via PHP that would toggle this script between the proper status of the start/stop button and starting the timer on pageload or starting it on click of the start/stop button.

```
  (function(d) {
    'use strict';
   var seconds = 0, si, h0, m0, s0, flag = true;

   var timer = d.getElementById( 'tiles' ),
       start = d.getElementById( 'start' ),
       reset = d.getElementById( 'reset' );

   timer.innerHTML = '<span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>';

   start.addEventListener('click', 
     function() {
         if ( flag === true ) {
           seconds ++;
           si = setInterval(  
             function(){
              h0 = pad( parseInt( seconds / 3600 ) );
              m0 = pad( parseInt( seconds / 60 % 60 ) );
              s0 = pad( seconds % 60 );
              timer.innerHTML = '<span>' + h0 + '</span><span>' + m0 + '</span><span>' + s0 + '</span>';
              seconds ++;
         }, 1000 );
              start.textContent = 'stop';
              flag = false;
             }
         else {
              clearInterval(si);
              start.textContent = 'start'; 
              flag = true;
       }}, false );

   reset.addEventListener('click', 
     function() {
          clearInterval( si );
          start.textContent = 'start'; 
          flag = true;
          timer.innerHTML = '<span>00</span><span>00</span><span>00</span>';
          seconds = 0;
       }, false );

   function pad( n ) {
     return ( n < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + n;
    }
  }(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's enough for you just to change

```
start.addEventListener('click'...)
```

to

```
start.addEventListener('load'...)
```

Here's MDN Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: I did try changing the click to load but it doesn't work.  Not only does the timer not start on page load, clicking the buttons no longer works as well.

http://schw.im/timer.html

Comment: You can try `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` - The **DOMContentLoaded** event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. 
Or `window.addEventListener('load', ... )` - The **load** event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.